# Model returns only NaN values on GTXA5000 but not on 1080TI

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras, cuda, nvidia

I have replaced a GTX 1080TI graphics card with a GTX A5000 in a desktop machine and reinstalled Ubuntu to upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04 in order to meet requirements.
But now I can't retrain or predict with our current model; When loading the model, Keras hangs for a very long time and all predicted results are NaN values.
We use Keras 2.2.4 with tensorflow 2.1.0 and Cuda 10.1.243, which I installed using Conda and I have tried with different drivers.

[image: Software & Updates - Additional Drivers]

If I put the old GTX 1080 TI card back in to the machine the code works fine.

Any idea of what can be wrong - can it be the case that the A5000 does not support the same models as an old 1080TI card?

Comment: CUDA 10.1 doesn't support Ampere cards

Comment: Okay thanks, I see that now: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/ampere-compatibility-guide/index.html#verifying-ampere-compatibility-using-cuda-11-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can confirm that this setup works on the GTX A5000

- CUDA: 11.6.0
- Tensorflow: 2.7.0

Driver Version: 510.47.03

Thanks to @talonmies for his comment.